# PyQGIS 3: How can pie charts have a fixed size when automating the process?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5

I'm unsure how to automate the process for PyQGIS to update the pie charts to a fixed size of 12.
The approach I used is not working out and no pie charts are being created.

[image]

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

diagram = QgsPieDiagram()

ds = QgsDiagramSettings()

dColors = {'Field1': QColor('#5a09a6'),'Field2': QColor('#ff9200')}

ds.categoryColors = dColors.values()
ds.categoryAttributes = dColors.keys()
ds.sizeType = 0
ds.categoryLabels = ds.categoryAttributes

dr = QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer()
#dr.setClassificationField('SAMPLE NUM')
dr.setDiagram(diagram)
dr.setDiagramSettings(ds)

lyr.setDiagramRenderer(dr)
dls = QgsDiagramLayerSettings()

lyr.setDiagramLayerSettings(dls)
lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent a lot of time trying to find the method to check 'Fixed size' or/and uncheck 'Scaled size' options and it was not possible. However, I found out a totally equivalent approach by using following code. The key was in to use a high number (1000000) in 'setLowerValue' method of **QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer** class to avoid 'Scaled size' in the field used as base of classification.

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

diagram = QgsPieDiagram()

ds = QgsDiagramSettings()

dColors = {'Field1': QColor('#5a09a6'),'Field2': QColor('#ff9200')}

ds.categoryColors = dColors.values()
ds.categoryAttributes = dColors.keys()
ds.categoryLabels = ds.categoryAttributes
ds.sizeType = 0 #0 = Millimeters, 1 = Map Units, 2 = Pixels, 4 = Points, 5 = Inches

# Set renderer:
dr = QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer()
dr.setLowerValue(1000000)
dr.setUpperSize(QSizeF(12, 12))
dr.setClassificationField('field1')
dr.setDiagram(diagram)
dr.setDiagramSettings(ds)

lyr.setDiagramRenderer(dr)
dls = QgsDiagramLayerSettings()

lyr.setDiagramLayerSettings(dls)
lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

I ran above code with following vector layer; where it can be observed in its attributes table 'field1' and 'field2' fields with different arbitrary values.

[image]

Result with Pie Diagram was as follows (Observe that Size scale was placed in 12):

[image]

I also applied manually 'Fixed size' option and result remained unchanged; as it can be observed in following image. I ran the script again and result was identical. It worked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this really answered my question. I never would have gotten this answer by myself.

Comment: You're welcome. So, you could mark as accepted this answer. Thanks in advance.